# Removing Controls programmatically NOT working as expected

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have 11 panels in each tabpage of a tabcontrol and want to remove 10 panels. so I wrote this code:

```
        var PnlsToRemove = tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<Panel>()
            .Where(p => !p.Name.StartsWith("BasePanel"));
        foreach (var pnl in PnlsToRemove)
            pnl.Dispose();
```

but after tracing I wondered that remove order is alternate!
means that when above code runs just panels 0,2,4,6,8,10 will remove and the others remains.
so I should put my code in a loop to remove panels alternately like this:

```
    while (tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<Panel>().Count() != 1)
    {
        var PnlsToRemove = tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<Panel>()
            .Where(p => !p.Name.StartsWith("BasePanel"));
        foreach (var pnl in PnlsToRemove)
            pnl.Dispose();
    }
```

in this case(for 10 panels) while() loops 4 times to remove all the panels.

NOTICE: all of my panels exist in "PnlsToRemove" and this bug occurs on execution of "PnlsToRemove" in foreach.

**So, what's wrong with my code?**
**Why `foreach()` jumps from next panel?**

*I think every thing is clear!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlying collection is being mutated as you remove the panels from the list, and this is apparently being reflected in the values seen by the "foreach". The solution is to store the values into a new collection and iterate over that. You should be able to do this by adding a ".ToList()" to your definition of PnlsToRemove

Comment: I used .ToList<Panel>() according to your advice. and it worked well. but I didnt underestand what was the problem?
means that why "being mutated as I remove the panels from the list" ?

Comment: A lot of LINQ methods result in lazy evaluation, which means that they won't make a copy of an underlying enumeration if they don't have to.

Imagine that you have an array, and instead of copying it you simply remember an index. The "get next element" operation will increment the index and return the next value from the array. We start with element zero. It gets returned and the index is updated to one. But now you're removing element zero from the array, so what's currently index one is what used to be index two. etc.